# Why am I getting an undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

So I created a function in a .js file that I linked to an html page, this is my function :

```
function produitListe1(x){
    var x = new String("25678");
    var a = x.split(", ");
    var sResultat;

    for(var i=0; i < x.length;i++){
        sResultat = sResultat + ("<ul>" + "<li>"  + x[i] + "</li>"  + "</ul>");
    }
    return sResultat;
}
```

and then to show the function result on my page I create another function which goes like this

```
(function (){
    var aLesDiv = document.querySelectorAll("#global div");
    aLesDiv[0].innerHTML = produitListe1(2,5,6,7,8);
}) ();
```

When I load the page I get my string on differents li's..but I get a random undefined call at the top, why?

Comment: `"25678".split(', ')` gives you the same result as `"25678".split()`

Comment: Try doing `x = undefined + "foo";` and see what the value of `x` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What is the point of the argument `x` if you're rediclaring it inside the function.
2. The way you are calling the function, I think what you are trying to do is use the [**arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object of the function.

Try this:

```
function produitListe1(){
    var sResultat = ""; // this should be initialized
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sResultat += "<ul><li>"  + arguments[i] + "</li></ul>"; // += is better
    }
    return sResultat;
}
```

`arguments` is a local variable defined inside each function, it's an array-like object that contains all the parameters passed to the function when it's been called.

```js
function foo() {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    console.log("Parameter #" + (i+1) + ": " + arguments[i]);
}


foo(1, "R2D2", 13.56, true);
```

Comment: The arguments object is actually way more convenient! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because the first time your for loop is executed, `sResultat` has not yet been assigned a value (and is therefore undefined), and you are assigning it to itself (undefined) `+ ("<ul>" + "<li>"  + x[i] + "</li>"  + "</ul>")`

Try initializing `sResultat` as an empty string (`var sResultat = "";`) instead of just `var sResultat;`

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `sResultat` with an empty string.

```
var sResultat = '';
```

```js
function produitListe1() {
    var sResultat = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sResultat = sResultat + ("<ul>" + "<li>" + arguments[i] + "</li>" + "</ul>");
    }
    return sResultat;
}

(function() {
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = produitListe1(2, 5, 6, 7, 8);
})();
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```